# ruby gsub and ordering replacement like in preg_replace

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have folowing function from php

```
pattern = "/^(.+)\/s3\/aws4_request\\n.+$/s"
result = preg_replace(pattern,'$1/s3aws4_request'."\n".$hashedCanonicalRequest, $rawStringToSign);
```

in ruby

```
pattern = /^(.+)\/s3\/aws4_request\\n.+$/
result = params[:headers].gsub(pattern, "$1/s3/aws4"+"\n"+hashed)
```

How to make ordering work in gsub ? I mean those $1 and $ ? can u explain ?

Update full

```
Parameters: {"headers"=>"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20180620T172236Z\n20180620/eu-west-2/s3/aws4_request\nPOST\n/65f9a73f-f7f5-4e9e-8e0e-e1c6afaa83c9.jpg\nuploads="}
hashedCanonicalRequest = "test"
pattern_two = /^(.+)\/s3\/aws4_request\n.+$/
stringToSign =  params[:headers].gsub(pattern_two, '\1/s3/aws4_request'+"\n"+ hashedCanonicalRequest)
# "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20180620T172051Z\n20180620/eu-west-2/s3/aws4_request\ntest\n/65f9a73f-f7f5-4e9e-8e0e-e1c6afaa83c9.jpg\nuploads="
```

Comment: use `\1` etc in case of ruby.  `"kiddorails".gsub(/(kid)do.*/, '\1oruby') #=> 'kidoruby'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\1` etc to used captured groups in replacement:

```
str = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/prod/s3/aws4_request\nfoo'
pattern = /^(.+)\/s3\/aws4_request\\n.+$/
str.gsub(pattern, '\1/s3/aws4'+"\n")
# => "http://s3.amazonaws.com/prod/s3/aws4\n"
```

**Edit**:

```
 str = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20180620T172236Z\n20180620/eu-west-2/s3/aws4_request\nPOST\n/65f9a73f-f7f5-4e9e-8e0e-e1c6afaa83c9.jpg\nuploads="

 pattern =  /^(.+)\/s3\/aws4_request.*/m # .* to capture everythign after aws_request, m for multiline, let's regex scan across \n
 str.gsub(pattern, '\1/s3/aws4'+"\n")
 #=> "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20180620T172236Z\n20180620/eu-west-2/s3/aws4\n"
```

Comment: thanks it works but my regexp isnt perfect. I would like to replace the last match and not append rest. i mean I have `str=asdasdasd/s3/aws4_request\nSomethingMore`and i want to replace this with this `\1/s3/aws4`+"\n"` but not append `SomethingMore`.

Comment: `SomethingMore` isn't getting appended as you can see in example in my answer. Can you give a more definite sample string, pattern and expectation?

Comment: @hodiecode updated my answer to reflect the correct regex you should be using.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What i wanted to do is to translete this to ruby `$stringToSign = preg_replace("/^(.+)\/s3\/aws4_request\\n.+$/s", '$1/s3/aws4_request'."\n".$hashedCanonicalRequest, $rawStringToSign)` the thing is it supposed to change all after aws4_request. Why then here is the operator `/s` not `/m`

Comment: These are called as regex modifiers. `/s` in PHP/Java etc is PCRE-DOTALL modifier, which matches all characters (including newlines), ruby implements it with `/m`. So, in hindsight, your regex is perfect if you could replace `/s` at with `/m`

Comment: Thanks kiddorails for patience with explaining everything !!